# Can't use jQuery referenced from a http url in a QUnit test

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

I try to include jquery in my QUnit test like this:

```
/// <reference path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" />
```

However, this line:

```
var input = $("<input type='text'/>");
```

will give me errors like:

> 1.Died on test #1: '$' is undefined

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are doing .NET development in Visual Studio? That's the only place I've seen the `/// <reference ... />` stuff. That is not actually including the source in your page, it is only [used for the IntelliSense reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2007/11/06/jscript-intellisense-a-reference-for-the-reference-tag.aspx) in your IDE. If you want to iunclude jQuery in your tests then you'll need to include it in your QUnit HTML file with a `<script>` tag just like any other reference:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- and then all of your QUnit stuff... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/qunit.css">
    <script src="path/to/qunit.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/your/tests.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The tests only consist of js files... When the jquery js file was on the fs, it was included

Comment: QUnit requires an HTML file, my guess is that it's buried in whatever plugin you're using (there is no other way to run QUnit tests). That said, if the local file using `/// <reference ...>` was working, and it is not using a remote file (`http://code.jquery.com...`) then that would be a problem with the plugin (and/or the IDE) and not something easily solved.